# angular 15 service worker stuck after reload

Tags: angular, service-worker

I'm using service worker with angular 15.
Currently, when I got a new version, I show a modal and if the user clicks Yes, the page is reloaded.

For an unknown reason, after reloading the page, the service worker gets stuck like follow:
[image]

In theory, there is a life saver function called `self.skipWaiting()` but not sure if we can call it in the default way angular gave us to handle the service worker.

I try an empty app from scratch and when I get a new version and reload the page, the service worker continues working as expected.

1. Do you have any idea what is the root cause of the problem?
2. Can a bug in another service cause this problem when reloading?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Finally, I found the solution to the problem.**

**Problem**

1. My page already has an active service worker.
2. After downloading a new version and reloading the page, a new service worker is installed but is not activated immediately, it will wait for an opportunity to become activated.

At this point, it seems like it will wait forever, even if the user reloads the page nothing will change.

**Solution**

First of all, we need to understand service worker lifecicle (links at the bottom)

1. Calling the `self.skipWaiting()` the problem is solved but I didn't found an option on the API Angular 15 provides.
2. I just waited for a while and I noticed the service worker become active again automtically.

Why ?

Without calling `self.skipWaiting()`, a waiting service worker will only become active once the currently active service worker is released and becomes redundant.

A scenario like this can only occurs in two ways:

1. If the user has navigated away from the page, thereby releasing the previous active worker.
2. If a specified period of time has passed, thereby releasing the previous active worker.

**Useful links**

- https://dev.to/gelopfalcon/service-worker-and-its-self-skipwaiting-44o5
- https://web.dev/service-worker-lifecycle/